# Exporting custom mesh from Maya in Vray

Tags: c++, rendering, maya

In a Maya plugin written in C++, I need to be able to render some custom-meshes using Vray. Vray comes with a library called GeomStaticMesh to easily pass and render these meshes.

While I could successfully render them (code a bit too long to paste here), they are not displayed in the exported .vrscene file, preventing distributed rendering. Would someone have a basic example of a maya/Vray plugin that allows rendering some meshes ?

Comment: You might be better served by contacting the Maya SDK support or using their developer support platform/forum, assuming they have either or both. Or since you problem seems to be more related to VRay, use their support channels.

Comment: Thanks Niklas, that's what I did but am missing, for the moment, good feedback on this request.